# Recreate Jtable or remove all rows and add new rows?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, defaulttablemodel

I have a JTable and a DefaultTableModel, I want to delete all the rows of JTable every 3 secondes and add new rows to the JTable. Considering the performance, What's the best choice to do that, recreate Jtable or remove all rows and add rows?

Comment: *"renew Jtable.."* What does that mean? *"..or remove all rows and addrows"* That's the approach I'd pursue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What's the best choice to do that, renew Jtable or remove all rows and addrows?

If you recreate the JTable, all the renderers and editors will be recreated for the table.

If you change the TableModel, then the table will need to recreate the TableColumnModel, and all the TableColumns based on the new TableModel.

There will be many more objects that need to be created to support the JTable/TableModel relationship.

Removing rows and adding rows, will just cause the table to repaint the new data using all the current renderers. I would say this is more efficient. And instead of adding rows one at a time, you should add all the rows at once

Comment: How can I add all the rows at once ?

Comment: The DefaultTableMode gives you access to the "dataVector" variable that holds the rows of data. So you extend the DefaultTableModel to create a custom method that:  1) removes all the rows 2) add all the rows of data to the dataVector 3) invoke the fireTableDataChanged(...) method.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a tablemodel that digs into your data object. As soon as you change the underlying data object, you call fireTableDataChanged().

From the JavaDoc for AbstractTableModel#fireTableDataChanged():

> Notifies all listeners that all cell values in the table's rows may have changed. The number of rows may also have changed and the JTable should redraw the table from scratch. The structure of the table (as in the order of the columns) is assumed to be the same.